# Flutter search words by alphabets

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an array in which I have name of string I want to add search by textField

Example I have name in array which is `Onion` when I type on it will show the list which contain name `on`

My array looks like this right now

[{ItemID: 1, Name: JBL E45BTTEL}, {ItemID: 1, Name: Audionic},{ItemID: 1, Name: Sony}]

i am doing like this

```
      Container(
        height: Height * 0.08,
        width: Width * 0.9,
        child: TextFormField(
          onChanged: (value) {
            print(value);
            print(
                'full result ${globalCategoryProduct.globalCategoryProductArray}');
            var result = globalCategoryProduct.globalCategoryProductArray
                .where((item) => item.Name.toLowerCase()
                    .contains(value.toLowerCase())
                    .toList());
            print(result);
          },
          onSaved: (value) {},
        
        ),
      ),
```

When i print result its showing nothing.

Comment: try removing `.toList()`

Comment: @ibrahimxcool same no result

Comment: What is the output you're getting?

Comment: @Theepag its showing nothing right now. no error no output

Comment: @Andy So, when you type `on`, do you want all the words which have `on` in them or just the ones that start with `on`?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad all words which have on

Comment: @Andy Ok, and do you want to find the exact map whose `Name` has `on` or just the name itself?

Comment: Post your logcat whatever printing in your log.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
 static final List<String> cities = [
    'Beirut',
    'Damascus',
    'San Fransisco',
    'Rome',
    'Los Angeles',
    'Madrid',
    'Bali',
    'Barcelona',
    'Paris',
    'Bucharest',
    'New York City',
    'Philadelphia',
    'Sydney',
  ];

  static List<String> getSuggestions(String query) {
    List<String> matches = <String>[];
    matches.addAll(cities);

    matches.retainWhere((s) => s.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()));
    return matches;
  }
```

This will return the match cases

```
getSuggestions("B")
```

returns `[Beirut, Bali, Barcelona, Bucharest]`